# Creating a Class with 2 double values in C++

Tags: c++, class, object

In C++ I am trying to create a class Point2D that contains two double values. All data members and functions should be public.

For Public Members there should be

- double x
- double y

For Constructors

- the default constructor should initialize x and y to 0.0
- Point2D(double in_x, double in_y)

  - sets x and y to in_x and in_y

For non-member Functions

- void GetResult(Point2D p1, Point2D p2)

  - Prints x and y values for both

This is the code I have so far, can somebody please point out my errors?

Point2D.h

```
#ifndef POINT2D_H
#define POINT2D_H

class Point2D
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;

Point2D();
Point2D(double,double);

};

void GetResult(Point2D, Point2D);

#endif
```

Point2D.cpp

```
#include "Point2D.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Point2D::Point2D()
{
    x = 0.0;
    y = 0.0;
}

Point2D::P1(double in_x, double in_y)
{
    x = in_x;
    y = in_y;
}

Point2D::P2(double in_x, double in_y)
{
    x = in_x;
    y = in_y;
}

void GetResult(Point2D P1, Point2D P2)
{
    cout << P1.x << " " << P1.y << endl;
    cout << P2.x << " " << P2.y << endl;
}
```

TestCheckPoint1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point2D.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Point2D Point1;
    Point1.x = 1.0;
    Point1.y= 2.0;

    Point2D Point2;
    Point2.x= 1.0;
    Point1.y= 2.0;

    GetResult(Point1, Point2);
}
```

Comment: What is the question? ... if you compiled the code and get errors, what are the error messages? (append them to the question, not in a comment)

Comment: Not sure what the P1 and P2 functions are, they look like two misnamed copies of the missing constructor. You might consider avoiding `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but it is clear you have a bit of misunderstanding about overloaded constructors and declaring instances of your class. For starters, you don't need the functions:

```
Point2D::P1(double in_x, double in_y)
{
    x = in_x;
    y = in_y;
}

Point2D::P2(double in_x, double in_y)
{
    x = in_x;
    y = in_y;
}
```

You simply need a single constructor for your `Point2D` class that takes two `double` values, e.g.

```
Point2D::Point2D(double in_x, double in_y)
{
    x = in_x;
    y = in_y;
}
```

Then in `main()` you need to declare and <s>initialize</s> default constuct two-instances of class `Point2D` providing the desired values to `x` and `y` before calling `GetResult`, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point2D.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Point2D Point1 (1.0, 2.0);
    Point2D Point2 (1.0, 2.0);

    GetResult(Point1, Point2);
}
```

(**note:** You can provide an *initializer lists* that allow initialization of the class members, see [Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). You could provide an initializer list for your constructor with, e.g. `Point2D() : x(0), y(0) {};` and the overload `Point2D(double, double);`. Your constructor definition would simply be `Point2D::Point2D(double in_x, double in_y) : x(in_x), y(in_y) {}` and the compiler would initialize `x, y` to `0, 0` if created with `Point2D Point1;` or set `x, y` to values provided as `Point2D Point2 (1.0, 2.0);`)

You did a very good job including the *Header Guards* around the contents of `Point2D.h` to prevent multiple inclusion if included in more than one file. The complete header and source files for `Point2D` could be:

```
#ifndef POINT2D_H
#define POINT2D_H

class Point2D
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;

    Point2D();
    Point2D(double,double);

};

void GetResult(Point2D, Point2D);

#endif
```

and

```
#include "Point2D.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Point2D::Point2D()
{
    x = 0.0;
    y = 0.0;
}

Point2D::Point2D(double in_x, double in_y)
{
    x = in_x;
    y = in_y;
}

void GetResult(Point2D P1, Point2D P2)
{
    cout << P1.x << " " << P1.y << endl;
    cout << P2.x << " " << P2.y << endl;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Compiling and running would result in:

```
$ ./bin/TestCheckPoint1
1 2
1 2
```

**Note:** there is no need to `using namespace std;` in `main()` at all, and you really shouldn't include the entire standard namespace anywhere. Simply remove both calls and add `std::` to your two `cout` calls and two calls to `endl` (or just use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl;`). See [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696)

Instead simply use:

```
void GetResult(Point2D P1, Point2D P2)
{
    std::cout << P1.x << " " << P1.y << '\n';
    std::cout << P2.x << " " << P2.y << '\n';
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Maybe also point out that currently the doubles are not being *initialized*. They are being default constructed and then assigned to. They should be initialized in the constructors initialization list.

Comment: After including the note on the use of the *initializer list*, from a learning standpoint based on the question, the default constructor was probably the simplest introduction, or way, to clear up the confusion. The C++11 initializer lists add flexibility, but also add an additional layer complexity for setting member values. Both are covered now.

Comment: The constructors initialization list - as in `Point2D() : x(0), y(0) {};` is not new in C++11, that has existed since C++98.

Comment: I was just going by note: (2) in the cppreference link. I'm not sure when it showed up. I started when Borland was DOS based... I'll just remove the when it showed up reference. Thanks. Now I'll have to go look up the 98 introduction.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - are you sure about that one? Cpprefernce is rarely wrong and their note (2) to [Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) clearly says C++11. Before I start looking backwards through past standards, do you have a reference you were thinking of that might save some time?

Comment: Brace initialization and initializer lists and initializer list constructors are new since C++11. But the constructors *initialization list* (what is after the `:` and used to initialize members before the constructor body) has existed since C++98. And that last bit is what I've been talking about the whole time.